# Importing a UML model based on UML2 version 2.0.0 in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, uml, emf, papyrus, rhapsody

I have a UML model based on UML2 version 2.0.0 `(xmlns:uml="http://www.eclipse.org/uml2/2.0.0/UML")`. In eclipse I have latest version on Papyrus installed, which comes with UML2 version 2.5.0.

The model I have is a very simple model generated from Rhapsody, in which I have one `Requirement`(requirement_1), one `Block` and one `Operation`(test_req()) in Block. In the model, test_req() operation verifies the requirement_1 as shown in diagram below:
  [image]

Using Rhapsody XMI toolkit, I am exporting the model to XMI format and trying to import it to eclipse as Papyrus Project. When I import model into Papyrus Project, the Stereotype(**verify**) applied on dependency between test_req() and requirement_1 is not detected: [image]

As it can be seen in image, `<<verify>>` stereotype in not applied to `requirement_1`.

Can anyone explain why the stereotype is missing? Is it because of difference in versions of UML2? How can I fix this?

I am also posting my UML model for reference [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6236947/ProjectTestSysML_2.3_sysml.uml)

Comment: How can there be a dependency at all? `test_req()` is an operation in `block_2`.

Comment: I added test_req() in Requirement diagram ( as shown in the first figure) and created a dependency between test_req an requirement_1

Comment: What you show is a SysML model, did you install the Papyrus  SysML optional component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem here is that the Model I have is based on UML2 version 2.0.0 and in eclipse, I have the latest version of UML installed i.e. UML 2.5.0. So when I try to import my model into Papyrus project it uses UML2 version 2.5.0 and not 2.0.0 and so some stereotypes are not recognized.

I am able to fix my code which finds the existing relationships in model by adding following code to make sure UML2 version 2.0.0 is used:

```
ResourceSet set = new ResourceSetImpl();
UMLResourcesUtil.init(set);
set.getResourceFactoryRegistry().getExtensionToFactoryMap()
    .put(UMLResource.FILE_EXTENSION, UMLResource.Factory.INSTANCE);

set.getPackageRegistry().put(UMLPackage.eNS_URI, UMLPackage.eINSTANCE);

Map<URI, URI> uriMap = set.getURIConverter().getURIMap();
URI uri = URI.createURI("jar:file:/home/jars/org.eclipse.uml2.uml.resources_2.0.3.v200707131442.jar!/"); // for example
uriMap.put(URI.createURI(UMLResource.LIBRARIES_PATHMAP), uri.appendSegment("libraries").appendSegment(""));
uriMap.put(URI.createURI(UMLResource.METAMODELS_PATHMAP), uri.appendSegment("metamodels").appendSegment(""));
uriMap.put(URI.createURI(UMLResource.PROFILES_PATHMAP), uri.appendSegment("profiles").appendSegment(""));
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used before Rhapsody for generating codes from sysml diagrams to the eclipse based Windriver workbench.
I have no idea about xml import/exporting ,but when we were changing configuration to the eclipse style & setted compiler setting in the CPP_CFG section ,rhapsody was able to generated codes directly in the eclipse environment.
maybe this will works for you too.